# How to customise error message to add ID in Yii?

Tags: php, html, ajax, yii

Currently I am using `$form->error($user_model,'password')` this function to show error message which gives me output as `<div class="errorMessage">Please enter current password</div>` but I want to add id in same div. What changes I have to do for that?

Comment: what do you mean with dynamic id? Are you trying to customise the error message?

Comment: yes.I want to customise error message

Answer (score 0):

To customize error message you have to go to user model and change/add your message to `function rules()` array.

```
function rules() {
   return [
      ['password', 'required', 'message' => 'Your custom message'],
   ];
}
```

Check [`CRequiredValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CRequiredValidator) class for more information.

---

To apply some custom ID:

```
$form->error($error_model, 'password', ['id' => 'My-super-custom-id']);
```

just it will break your error messages output when using yii-js methods.